# Sql truncate to decimal places on condition

Tags: sql-server-2008, truncate

I have a requirement

```
DECLARE @Test TABLE   
(Id int not null,
 AMOUNT decimal(20,3) not null)
 Insert into @Test values(1, 100.943)
 Insert into @Test values(2, 100.000)
 Insert into @Test values( 3,100.943)


SELECT Id,
case 
when Id = 2 then 
 CAST(ROUND(AMOUNT,2,4) AS DECIMAL(19,2))  
 else AMOUNT
 end as AMOUNT
 from @Test
```

but it does not produce the desired result. 
The result returned is

```
Id  AMOUNT
1   100.943
2   100.000
3   100.943
```

How can I get the Amount to be truncated to 2 decimals only when the Id = 2

The expected result is

```
Id  AMOUNT
1   100.943
2   100.00
3   100.943
```

Comment: What result do you get?

Comment: Your query itself working fine check here http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/31700  and this too  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/31701

Comment: edited my question with the result I get and What I am expecting

Answer (score 2):

You could do this:

```
SELECT Id,
case 
when Id = 2 then 
 ROUND(AMOUNT,2,2) 
 else AMOUNT
 end as AMOUNT
 from @Test
```

The round has an input as [ROUND ( numeric_expression , length [ ,function ] )](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175003.aspx). Which means that you are rounding it to 4 `decimal`